# Stretching/Shrinking Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am making an android game. I test my application on Galaxy sII. I have made much progress. Unfortunately, I ignored to test it for other devices. I knew that I would encounter a different resolution problem of different type devices. But I thought I could handle by arranging my coordinate values. But now I see it is very hard task. I cannot return to starting point because I have written quite a lot code.

My question is that is there any method which I can stretch/shrink my canvas to the other resolutions despite I gave my values for 800x480?

P.S.: I get my canvas by `Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();`in my thread.

Thanks

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I just postponed it. I guess I will have to determine a ratio (between for example 480x800 and 240x320) in the beginning of the drawing section and multiply it with my values when I need.

Comment: I'm curious to see how you deal with different aspect ratios. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Actually my application is a kind of puzzle game and having slightly wider or thinner images is not a big problem for it. At least I hope so :).

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely competent on the matter, but you should be able to do matrix transformations on the Canvas. See if this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391670/canvas-matrix-transformation) will provide a starting point. Also, read up on the matter in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

EDIT: It now occurred to me that this could place objects or parts of objects outside the screen or introduce perspective problems...

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a draw to a Canvas as a View and set the layout params in the xml.
This would allow the Canvas View to change with each resolution dynamically and with minimal effort.

Like a SurfaceView.

Answer (score 1):

```
    canvas.scale(float scaleX, float scaleY). Try this.
```

Also consider the tips in the documentation. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html